# How to delete a node from a linked list

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, nodes

Hey guys I wrote this deleteNode() method that works if I used numbers(int) but doesn't when I try to pass a string in. I'm printing out a String[] list of names and I'm trying to delete a certain name off the list. When I enter a name, it prints "Node not found". Like I said, if I print out a list of numbers it works great but if I change up and print a string it doesnt. Any help is appreciated.

```
   public class BigNode {


   public String dataitems; 
    public BigNode next; 
    BigNode front ;

    public void initList(){
        front = null;
    }

    public BigNode makeNode(String number){
        BigNode newNode;
        newNode = new BigNode();
        newNode.dataitems = number;
        newNode.next = null;
        return newNode;
    }

    public boolean isListEmpty(BigNode front){
        boolean balance;
        if (front == null){
            balance = true;
        }
        else {
            balance = false;
        }
        return balance;

    }

    public BigNode findTail(BigNode front) {
        BigNode current;
        current = front;
        while(current.next != null){
            //System.out.print(current.dataitems);
            current = current.next;

        } //System.out.println(current.dataitems);
        return current;
    }

    public void addNode(BigNode front ,String number){
        BigNode tail;
        if(isListEmpty(front)){
            this.front = makeNode(number);
        } 
        else {
            tail = findTail(front);
            tail.next = makeNode(number);
        }
    }
    public void deleteNode(BigNode front, String value) {
        BigNode curr, previous = null; boolean found; 

            if (!isListEmpty(front)){
                curr = front;
                found = false;

                while ((curr.next != null) && (!found)) {
                    if(curr.dataitems.equals(value)) {
                        found = true;
                    } 
                    else {
                        previous = curr;
                        curr = curr.next;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    if(curr.dataitems.equals(value)) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    if (curr.dataitems.equals(front.dataitems)){ // front.dataitems may be wrong .dataitems 
                        front = curr.next;
                    } else { 

                        previous.next = curr.next;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Node not found!");
                    //curr.next = null; // Not sure If this is needed
                }
        } 
            showList(front);
    }




    public void printNodes(String[] len){


        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < len.length; j++){

            addNode(front, len[j]);
        }  showList(front);
    }

    public void showList(BigNode front){
        BigNode current;
        current = front;
        while ( current.next != null){
            System.out.print(current.dataitems + ", ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println(current.dataitems);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                   String[] names = {"Billy Joe", "Sally Mae", "Joe Blow", "Tasha Blue"}; 

        BigNode x = new BigNode(); 
                   x.printNodes(names); 
                   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                   String delete = in.next();
                  x.deleteNode(x.front, delete); 
          }
```

String[] names = {name1, name2, name3, name4}

-First it prints the list, then ask what name to delete.

Comment: ok heres the majority of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I've found out what's wrong with the sample code you've posted.

You're calling `Scanner.next()` which reads a single *word*. All of your node values are *two words*. So if I type in "Sally Mae" it's *actually* just looking for "Sally".

This has nothing to do with the majority of the code in `BigNode` (although that could certainly be made more elegant). Basically this:

```
String delete = in.next();
```

should be

```
String delete = in.nextLine();
```

Now I would *strongly* suggest that you *don't* just change the code, but instead think about the ways you could have diagnosed this for yourself:

- Add logging to your code to show value you were looking for, and each value as you tested it
- Use a debugger to step through the code, watching variables
- Use unit tests to test the code - those wouldn't have shown you the problem (as it wasn't in code you'd usually write tests for) but they would have given you greater confidence that the problem *wasn't* in the tested code.

If you try some or preferrably *all* of those approaches, you'll have learned a lot more from this question than just how to use `Scanner`...

---

In various places, you're comparing string *references* by using the == operator. That will only find your node if you pass in a reference to one of the actual string objects which exists in the list - not a reference to an *equal* string object.

You want something like:

```
if (curr.dataitems.equals(value))
```

(but with careful `null` checking).

Comment: @TMan: Then you need to post a short but *complete* program. You still haven't shown us the code for BigNode, for example.

Comment: Ok I posted the necessary code. You think it could be the way I'm passing in the name I want to delete?

Comment: @TMan: The code you've posted always gives a NullPointerException. It never even uses `names`.

Comment: yes I'm sorry, thats b/c x.printNodes(names) needs to be in the main method.

Comment: @TMan: It's *very* odd for a method called `printNodes` to *add* nodes to the list... and an empty list still shouldn't throw a NullPointerException. Still, I'll look into it...

Comment: did u mean to say String delete = in.nextLine();? what is diff. btwn scanner and scanned that you have above?

Comment: @TMan: Yes, thanks - fixed. They should both have been `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using String.equals comparison instead of == comparison,.

```
if(curr.dataitems == value) {
```

should be:

```
if(curr.dataitems.equals(value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You do comparisons with `==`.  For `int` this compares the values, but for `String` only the references. So is you want to remove a String with the same value but in different objects this will fail.

Use `String.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use equals() for comparing object values, not == . For instance, in your code this line:

```
curr.dataitems == value
```

should have been written as:

```
curr.dataitems.equals(value)
```